# PHP how to execute actions once then auto reload the page

Tags: php, microsoft-edge, reload

i would like to create a php page that at first open two links with edge dev and after having execute the code, reload the page but without repeat the open link action again.

For the reload i'm using:

```
<HEAD>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20; url=frmBst.php" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <base target="content">
</HEAD>
```

For open the link i'm using

````
<A HREF="microsoft-edge:https://www....>Pw365</A>```
````

Questions:

1. how can i open edge dev instead as edge?
2. how can i automatically open the link once they start the main page without have a link to click?
3. how can i avoid that after the reload the link will be
   open again?

Thanks

Comment: 2. try to use `location.href`

Answer (score 0):

Below are the answers for your questions.

**1) how can i open edge dev instead as edge?**

I can see that you are adding **microsoft-edge:** before the link. If MS Edge legacy and MS Edge (Chromium) both browsers are available on the machine then it will launch the MS Edge legacy browser. If only MS Edge (Chromium) browser is available on the machine then it will launch the MS Edge (Chromium) browser.

**2) how can i automatically open the link once they start the main page without have a link to click?**

**3) how can i avoid that after the reload the link will be open again?**

From your last 2 questions, it looks like you want to automate the web page. If yes, PHP is not suitable for it. I suggest trying to check for the WebDriver. It supports many programming languages. You can choose which one you are familiar with. It can help you to properly automate the web page.

For more information, you can refer to the link below.

[Use WebDriver (Chromium) for test automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp)